# Short story about a person using a barrow to put stones into the sea. Maybe by Le Guin?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story during the 70s.  It had a small being using a barrow to put stones into the sea, maybe to build a causeway.  For some reason I kept thinking it was from a Le Guin collection.

It had that beauty and sadness which her stories often possessed.  I’d love to read it again!

Comment: Ahhh! I *totally* remember a story like that! Is it like an End of The World scenario, and the dude putting stones in the sea is more or less the only person who is **not** "Well f--k it! I am gonna party the rest of my time out." Can't recall who the author was, though.

Comment: Sounds like it!

Comment: @Tinkingbell - Don't you mean a wheelbarrow?  A barrow is an ancient burial mound.

Comment: @M.A.Golding "Barrow" is also a synonym for "wheelbarrow" per  Webster's Revised Unabridged English Dictionary.

Comment: Using "barrow" as a synonym for wheelbarrow has an archaic or provincial feel which is why an author might choose it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is by Ursula Le Guin. It is the short story [Things](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58825). I read it in The Wind's Twelve Quarters.

The protagonist is Lif, who is a brickmaker. I don't recall exactly what is about to cause the end of the world, but Lif decides to make use of the huge pile of newly made bricks he has to build a causeway into the sea. At the end of the story he and a widow (with whom he is romantically involved) walk out along his causeway into the sea. The ending is ambiguous. It isn't clear whether they drowned or not.

> He took her free hand and led her into the water. It was cold. It was bitter cold, and the cold light from the east behind them shone on the foam-lines hissing on the sand. When they stepped on the beginning of the causeway the bricks were firm under their feet, and the child had gone back to sleep on her shoulder in a fold of her cloak.
> ...
> Lifting his head to take the last step from what he had done towards no shore, he saw the shape riding the western water, the leaping light, the white flicker like a swallow’s breast catching the break of day. It seemed as if voices rang over the sea’s voice. What is it? he said, but her head was bowed to her baby, trying to soothe the little wail that challenged the vast babbling of the sea. He stood still and saw the whiteness of the sail, the dancing light above the waves, dancing on towards them and towards the greater light that grew behind them.
> Wait, the call came from the form that rode the grey waves and danced on the foam, Wait! The voices rang very sweet, and as the sail leaned white above him he saw the faces and the reaching arms, and heard them say to him, Come, come on the ship, come with us to the Islands.
> Hold on, he said softly to the woman, and they took the last step.

Comment: Thank you so much, @John Rennie!  And to @Lexible!  I shall go and find the story - and read it again!  Thanks again